# Background under a tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

There are a lot of questions about `background` but I haven't found the answer I want

I would like to use a picture (old paper) under the result of a tikzpicture.

Actually my code is

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex-dev
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newlength{\mywidth}
\newlength{\myheight}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pictsize}[2]{ % #1 = width, #2 = height
 \pgfextractx{\@tempdima}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{current bounding box}{south west}}
 {\pgfpointanchor{current bounding box}{north east}}}
 \global#1=\@tempdima
 \pgfextracty{\@tempdima}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{current bounding box}{south west}}
 {\pgfpointanchor{current bounding box}{north east}}}
 \global#2=\@tempdima
}
\makeatother
\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main}
\tikzset{paper/.style={%
execute at end picture={%
\pictsize{\mywidth}{\myheight}%
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background layer} 
\node[inner sep=0pt] (p) at (current bounding box.center)
     {\includegraphics[width=\mywidth,height=\myheight]{paper.png}};
\end{pgfonlayer}%
}}}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[paper]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (6,6);
\draw[line width=1cm] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My question :  Is it possible to avoid `\newlength{\mywidth}
\newlength{\myheight}` and the command `\pictsize` ? the tikzpicture and the background must have the same dimensions. With only TikZ !

[image]

Comment: @JohnKormylo  yes but it’s not a problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could clip the image using the bounding box, assuming the default size is large enough.

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main}
\tikzset{paper/.style={%
execute at end picture={%
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background layer} 
\clip (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\node[inner sep=0pt] (p) at (current bounding box.center)
     {\includegraphics{example-image}};
\end{pgfonlayer}%
}}}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[paper]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (6,6);
\draw[line width=1cm] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: good idea and i's simple

Answer (score 4):

Yes, of course. pgf stores the dimensions in `pgf@picmaxx`, `\pgf@picminx`, `pgf@picmaxy`, and `\pgf@picminy`, so you could just use them.

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{paper/.style={%
execute at end picture={%
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background layer} 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidth}{\pgf@picmaxx-\pgf@picminx}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myheight}{\pgf@picmaxy-\pgf@picminy}%
\node[inner sep=0pt] (p) at (current bounding box.center)
     {\includegraphics[width=\mywidth pt,height=\myheight pt]{example-image-duck}};
\end{pgfonlayer}%
}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[paper]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (6,6);
\draw[line width=1cm] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, `tikz` automatically loads `graphicx`, so this is really "only `tikz`". ;-)

Comment: One may use `\dimexpr` but I am not sure if that is really much better than defining two local macros (as opposed to introducing new lengths).

Comment: I forgot `pgf@picmaxx` ! I'm getting too old. Good answer and informations about `graphics`and `:dimexpr` . Thanks but the `clip` solves my problems